# need an email notification service for my job portal website in django without html

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, cron-task, email-notifications

I need an email notification service which sends emails to subscribed users who has subscribed for specific job location. If the location of the company and the subscribed location of the user are same an email should be sent to the user regarding the company details. also need to associate cron job which check for the new job postings and notify the users. This frequency should be tun-able. It can be 1day or 15mins.

my models:
company details:

```
class JobListing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null =True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="")
    description = models.TextField()
```

subscribed user:

```
class UserSubscription(models.Model):
     username = models.CharField(max_length=150,default="sample name")
     email_id = models.EmailField(unique=True)
     job_location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

serializers:

```
class JobListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = JobListing
         fields = '__all__'

class UserSubscriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = UserSubscription
         fields = '__all__'
```

views:

```
class UserSubscriptionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserSubscription.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSubscriptionSerializer


class JobListingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = JobListing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = JobListingSerializer
```

I want an email notification service and associate cron job with it.

Answer (score 0):

From your views function you can run a function to send an email base on the logic you mentioned.

You can use many services to deal with the sending email mechanism.

regarding cronjob: you can use django-crontab, you can read about it here:
https://pypi.org/project/django-crontab/